# Must I change my ASP MVC Authentication System for Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, forms-authentication

Some time ago I created a ASP MVC WebSite that used `Forms authentication` and `Sessions`. Now I'm going to publish it in a **WebRole** in Azure.

My question is, must I change something in the authentication system, or should it work?

If it should not work, could you please explain the problem?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995011/forms-authentication-provider-for-azure-mvc2-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't *have* to change your authentication system to use azure.  At the worst case (if you use AD integrated auth) you will need to set up a VPN tunnel using Azure Connect to connect your website to AD.

You can do the same if you have an on-prem SQL service, or any other source for authentication.

If you use ADFS, or any other passive auth then they will redirect as usual.